# Compare values Button type Radio with Selenium and JXL

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, jxl

The following code reads the spreadsheet cell values ​​with the JXL plugin and then compares these values with the values ​​on the page and chooses the matching value from the combo box.

How do I adapt this code to work with the radio button?

```
String valDesejado = aquisicaoAparelho;
boolean variavelVerificadora1 = false; // use boolean instead of int set to 0/1
Select verificaOpt = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("aquisicaoAparelho")));
System.out.println("Tamanho: " + verificaOpt.getOptions().size());
// as this loops, the variable 'option' contains the current loops' OPTION element
// you don't need to select the option to get its text so this loop should be much faster
// it selects the OPTION once the correct one is found
for (WebElement option : verificaOpt.getOptions())
{
    if (valDesejado.equalsIgnoreCase(option.getText()))
    {
        verificaOpt.selectByVisibleText(option.getText()); // select the OPTION match
        variavelVerificadora1 = true; // set the boolean to true to indicate we found a match
        break; // exits the for loop
    }
}

if (!variavelVerificadora1) // this is the equivalent of variavelVerificadora1 == false, it's basically saying if not true
{
    System.out.println("ALERTA: The Option" + valDesejado + " no comboBox \"aquisicaoAparelho\" not found.");
}
```

**Html code the page:**

```
<td align="left" class="label">
    <input type="radio" value="S" name="aquisicaoAparelho">Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" value="N" name="aquisicaoAparelho">Not&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" value="A" name="aquisicaoAparelho">both
</td>
```

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Comment: @JeffC I tried a number of ways , with implicit and explicit waits with WebElement but to no avail , did not put the code attempts here not to be polluted , but I tried yes, before you post here :)

Comment: You should add those to the question. It will help us see what you have tried and to narrow down the problem.